# Unity - Exporting and Importing Terrains

Tags: unity, terrain, modding

To provide modding support via Unity editor, I need to export terrains in editor and load the exported terrain in runtime.

Is this possible by any manner?

Comment: Do you want just terrain mesh or everything in it too?

Comment: @SP. Everything. Basically the whole terrain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on the terrain and click "Export Package", open the package in an archiving program then open the "archtemp.tar" from within that package.

Copy The "Asset" File and give it the file extension ".asset".

Comment: I successfully exported and imported the terrain in editor mode. Any tips on loading in runtime?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html).